# How to create a Sharing using parent field value?

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

Account OWD is Private
Objects in question OWD is Private
Objects in question has lookup relationships to Account

Account Criteria-based Sharing Rule allows public group A to access Accounts that has X in field Y

I have ~25 objects that need the same sharing rule, but the criteria-based sharing rule does not allow to use a lookup value in its parent (the Account).

My initial thought is to create an extra field Y on each object which can contain X and thereby allow access. This can't be a formula either, as they are not allowed for sharing rules either. This leaves me to setting this field by triggers on insert and updates on this field.

Please tell me there's an easier way? :D

Comment: If it's a master detail relationship with Account, change it to "Controlled by Parent" to have the Account's sharing control this record too. If it isn't then I think you need to do what you've suggested.

Comment: That would be too easy ;) These are all lookups